# How to position two images side by side in svg

Tags: css, svg, layout

I would like to position two loaded images side by side in svg without absolute position. 
I tried the position with help of an container and `float: left` or `display: flex`. But it doens´t work.

Here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWeBRv

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In SVG you'll need an absolute position for both. There is no practical way to have automatic layouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the width of the first image, and they will fit ok:

```css
#iconOne {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
 <svg width="200" height="200">
       <g>
            <image id="iconOne" width="30" height="30" xlink:href="iconOne.svg" />
            <image id="iconTwo" width="50" height="30" xlink:href="iconTwo.svg" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Otherwise, if you want to use standard HTML positioning, you must (as far as I know) rely on this, I mean, make separate HTML entities:

```css
.image {
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="image">
            <image id="iconOne" width="30" height="30" xlink:href="iconOne.svg" />
    </svg>
<svg class="image">
            <image id="iconTwo" width="50" height="30" xlink:href="iconTwo.svg" />
    </svg>
<svg class="image">
         <image id="iconThree" width="60" height="30" xlink:href="iconTwo.svg" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. But I need it a little bit more dynamically, later it could be possible to add more than two images like in this new codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpdKgX Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I have added another snippet

Comment: Thank you again. I though it would work but it doesn´t work, because I need   'position: absolute' at the container like in this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZpaqM Maybe there is a solution? Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't wrap it again in a svg element, wrap it in a div, otherwise normal CSS styling wont work